# ParseError thrown on Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress

Using the css/html built-in editor in Wordpress I have added some code the functions.php file but something wrong happened and the following error shows up every time I open the website:

```
 ParseError thrown
 syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file
```

I accessed the theme's functions.php file using the file manager and replaced it with the theme's original file and no errors show up in the code, However, the same error persists on opening the website. What could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Here's a portion of the functions.php file's content. The code I have added was in the end and I deleted it afterwards but the error persists.

```
 <?php
 /**
  * Buzz Store functions and definitions.
  *
  * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
  *
  * @package Buzz_Store
  */

 if ( ! function_exists( 'buzzstore_setup' ) ) :
 /**
  * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress 
 features.
  *
  * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
  * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, 
 such
  * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
  */
 function buzzstore_setup() {
    /*
     * Make theme available for translation.
      * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
      * If you're building a theme based on Buzz Store, use a find and replace
     * to change 'buzzstore' to the name of your theme in all the template files.
      */
     load_theme_textdomain( 'buzzstore', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    // WooCommerce Plugins Support
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

    // Set up the WordPress Gallery Lightbox
    add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-lightbox');

    /*
     * Let WordPress manage the document title.
     * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
      * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
      * provide it for us.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

    /*
     * Enable support for custom logo.
        */
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'width'       => 190,
        'height'      => 60,
        'flex-width'  => true,              
        'flex-height' => true,
        'header-text' => array( '.site-title', '.site-description' ),
    ) );

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/
    */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size('buzzstore-banner-image', 1350, 485, true); // banner
    add_image_size('buzzstore-news-image', 370, 285, true); // Home Blog
    add_image_size('buzzstore-news-details-image', 850, 385, true); // Details Blog
    add_image_size('buzzstore-cat-image', 275, 370, true);


    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'topmenu' => esc_html__( 'Top Menu', 'buzzstore' ),
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'buzzstore' ),
    ) );

    /*
     * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
     * to output valid HTML5.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'search-form',
        'comment-form',
        'comment-list',
        'gallery',
        'caption',
    ) );


function buzzstore_customize_partial_blogname() {
    bloginfo( 'name' );
}
function buzzstore_customize_partial_blogdescription() {
    bloginfo( 'description' );
}
```

Comment: _"What could be wrong?"_ - There could be a parse error somewhere. It's impossible for anyone to be able to help with the little information you've given. When you get that error, it should also say in which file and on what line the error occurs. If you post that code, we might be able to help. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks very much. Unfortunately, the error doesn't say anything about the location of the error. Anyway, I'm gonna insert the functions.php file now. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Check the web servers error log to see if you get more information, like a stack trace. Either way, we can't know what's wrong with your code if we can't see it. Btw, how are you adding code to `functions.php` using the html/css editor in WP?

Comment: Through the Wordpress dashboard --> cusromize --> html/css editor, I found the theme's style and functions file on the right editable.

Comment: I just wonder why the defective line isn't stated in the error. I even think it's not the functions.php that has something wrong with it. I even tried uploading all the theme again via the file manager and replacing the old one but in vain :(

Comment: Well, unless you manage to narrow down _where_ that happens, this question will be unanswerable.

Comment: What am I supposed to do? Why isn't the error's location depicted in the error message? How come I can know where the problem is? The site is big with so much code. I even replaced the whole theme but I can't get what's wrong! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @DouaAli, I'd like to help you narrow down the problem. We are looking for a syntax error that could be anywhere (as Magnus already mentioned). The first thing is not to edit anything and make sure that your evidence posted to StackOverflow keeps in-sync with your actual codebase. At first glance, there is effectively a syntax error in your functions.php, but since it's truncated, we really can't assure. Could you upload a full copy of your functions.php into a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com)?

Comment: Thanks very very much for your kindness. Here is the full code of the functions.php in the following pastebin
https://pastebin.com/5am6t37w

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code there is two error 
 closing bracket for the first function is not defined and if condition is not ended any where.

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'buzzstore_setup' ) ) :
 /**
  * Sets up theme defaults and registers support for various WordPress 
 features.
  *
  * Note that this function is hooked into the after_setup_theme hook, which
  * runs before the init hook. The init hook is too late for some features, 
 such
  * as indicating support for post thumbnails.
  */
 function buzzstore_setup() {
    /*
     * Make theme available for translation.
      * Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory.
      * If you're building a theme based on Buzz Store, use a find and replace
     * to change 'buzzstore' to the name of your theme in all the template files.
      */
     load_theme_textdomain( 'buzzstore', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );

    // Add default posts and comments RSS feed links to head.
    add_theme_support( 'automatic-feed-links' );

    // WooCommerce Plugins Support
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );

    // Set up the WordPress Gallery Lightbox
    add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-lightbox');

    /*
     * Let WordPress manage the document title.
     * By adding theme support, we declare that this theme does not use a
      * hard-coded <title> tag in the document head, and expect WordPress to
      * provide it for us.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'title-tag' );

    /*
     * Enable support for custom logo.
        */
    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'width'       => 190,
        'height'      => 60,
        'flex-width'  => true,              
        'flex-height' => true,
        'header-text' => array( '.site-title', '.site-description' ),
    ) );

    /*
     * Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/featured-images-post-thumbnails/
    */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    add_image_size('buzzstore-banner-image', 1350, 485, true); // banner
    add_image_size('buzzstore-news-image', 370, 285, true); // Home Blog
    add_image_size('buzzstore-news-details-image', 850, 385, true); // Details Blog
    add_image_size('buzzstore-cat-image', 275, 370, true);


    // This theme uses wp_nav_menu() in one location.
    register_nav_menus( array(
        'topmenu' => esc_html__( 'Top Menu', 'buzzstore' ),
        'primary' => esc_html__( 'Primary', 'buzzstore' ),
    ) );

    /*
     * Switch default core markup for search form, comment form, and comments
     * to output valid HTML5.
     */
    add_theme_support( 'html5', array(
        'search-form',
        'comment-form',
        'comment-list',
        'gallery',
        'caption',
    ) );

}
function buzzstore_customize_partial_blogname() {
    bloginfo( 'name' );
}
function buzzstore_customize_partial_blogdescription() {
    bloginfo( 'description' );
}
endif;
```